# pagination doesn't appear datatable

Tags: javascript, datatable, pagination, pdf-generation

There is a data table with export to PDF or Excel and print  buttons.But pagination doesn't appear. When I have looked examples most of them same as my project; when they put button, pagination doesn't appear.  How can I solve the problem? 
js code of Data table is below;

```
    var oTable = $('#datatables').dataTable({
                destroy: true,
                "bSort": false,
                dom: 'Bfrtip',
                buttons: [
                {
                    extend: 'excelHtml5',
                    footer: true ,
                    exportOptions: {
                        columns: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4,5,6,7]
                    }   
                },
                {
                    extend: 'pdfHtml5',
                    exportOptions: {
                        columns: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
                    },
                    customize: function (doc) {
                    //Remove the title created by datatTables
                    doc.content.splice(0, 1);
                    //Create a date string that we use in the footer. Format is dd-mm-yyyy
                    var now = new Date();
                    var jsDate = now.getDate() + '-' + (now.getMonth() + 1) + '-' + now.getFullYear();

              //      doc.pageMargins = [20, 60, 20, 30];
                    // Set the font size fot the entire document
                    doc.defaultStyle.fontSize = 9;
                    // Set the fontsize for the table header
                    doc.styles.tableHeader.fontSize = 9;
                    // Create a header object with 3 columns
                    // Left side: Logo
                    // Middle: brandname
                    // Right side: A document title
                    doc['header'] = (function () {
                        return {
                            columns: [

                                {
                                    alignment: 'left',
                                    italics: true,
                                    text: 'dataTables',
                                    fontSize: 18,
                                    margin: [10, 0]
                                },
                                {
                                    alignment: 'right',
                                    fontSize: 14,
                                    text: $("#drpIller option:selected").text() + "  " + $("#drpIlceler option:selected").text() 
                                }
                            ],
                            margin: 20
                        }
                    });
                    doc['footer'] = (function (page, pages) {
                        return {
                            columns: [
                                {
                                    alignment: 'left',
                                    text: ['Oluşturulma tarihi: ', { text: jsDate.toString() }]
                                },
                                {
                                    alignment: 'right',
                                    text: ['page ', { text: page.toString() }, ' / ', { text: pages.toString() }]
                                }
                            ],
                            margin: 20
                        }
                    });
                    var objLayout = {};
                    objLayout['hLineWidth'] = function (i) { return .5; };
                    objLayout['vLineWidth'] = function (i) { return .5; };
                    objLayout['hLineColor'] = function (i) { return '#aaa'; };
                    objLayout['vLineColor'] = function (i) { return '#aaa'; };
                    objLayout['paddingLeft'] = function (i) { return 4; };
                    objLayout['paddingRight'] = function (i) { return 4; };
                    doc.content[0].layout = objLayout;
                }
                },
                {
                    extend: 'print'
                }
                ],
                "responsive": true,
                "data": data,
                "columns": [             
                   { "data": "A", "autoWidth": true},
                   { "data": "S", "autoWidth": true},
                   { "data": "D", "autoWidth": true },
                   { "data": "E", "autoWidth": true},
                   { "data": "F", "autoWidth": true },
                   { "data": "G", "autoWidth": true }

                ],
               "bAutoWidth": false 
                }
            });
```

thanks your valuable for helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found answer at this link:
https://codepen.io/RedJokingInn/pen/XMVoXL
It is abouth dom  options.
It is solved When I write

```
"dom":  '<"dt-buttons"Bf><"clear">lirtp'
```

instead

```
 dom: 'Bfrtip'
```

tutorial at the link also consists printing page numbers and printing same sentence top of  every pages informations.

May be can help someone in the future.